# Hybrid Application development for Windows 7 Tablet

Tags: cordova, visual-studio-cordova

Can any one confirm if Cordova supports Application Development for windows 7 tablets.I am specifically looking for apps development with Cordova for Motion Computing Windows 7 Tablets [Link for details of the tablet](http://www.tabletpcreview.com/tabletreview/motion-computing-cl900-review-a-tablet-pc-for-the-enterprise/). I have referred [this Cordova link](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/4.0.0/guide_support_index.md.html) but not sure.

Answer (score 0):

No, Cordova apps are not supported on Win7, you can target Win8.0 and above.

Comment: Thanks , if Cordova doesn't support this device , can you suggest the development a approach for this device?